# Consecutive balls of the same color on a line

Tags: combinatorics

Fix a positive integer $k\geq 1$. $2k+1$ red balls and $2k+1$ blue balls are on a line in some order.

What is the least $n$ (in terms of $k$) such that we are always able to remove $n$ red balls and $n$ blue balls in a way that the remaining red balls are all together, and so are the remaining blue balls?

We may need to remove up to $k$ in the case that we have $k$ red balls, followed by $2k+1$ blue balls, and finally $k+1$ red balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the line in half and remove the minority colour on either side, of which there are at most $k$. Thus $n=k$ is sufficient, and you've already demonstrated that it's necessary.